# How to remove space around a character?

Tags: string, delphi

Say I have the following string:

```
s := 'This , is,       the Delphi  ,    World!';
```

I would like the following output:

```
Result := 'This,is,the Delphi,World!';
```

Basically I need a routine that strips *ALL* occurrences of spaces *ONLY* if they appears before or after the comma char (which is my delimiter), leaving intact spaces between other words.

Any help is much appreciated.

What do you think of this solution?

```
function RemoveSpacesAroundDelimiter(var aString: string; aDelimiter:
    string): string;
begin
  while AnsiContainsText(aString, aDelimiter + ' ') do
    begin
    aString := StringReplace(aString, ', ', aDelimiter, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    end;

  while AnsiContainsText(aString, ' ' + aDelimiter) do
    begin
    aString := StringReplace(aString, ' ' + aDelimiter, aDelimiter, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    end;

  Result := aString;
end;
```

### thanks

fabio

Comment: I don't know delphi, but you could split the string with comma as the delimiter, then call Trim (http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Trim) on each resulting substring, and then assemble your string again (there is probably a Join method that you can use on a list of strings)

Comment: Which version of Delphi? If you have XE or later you can use a regex to do this.

Comment: I prefer my solution with stringReplace, even if all the cases are not traited.

Comment: Your solution is more general because you can change the delimiter, but mine is 'lighter'. Just a remark : I think you don't need to pass your string as a Var parameter in your function as you use Result, unless you want to use it as a funciton or like a procedure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like a task for TStringList.

```
function UltraTrim(Value: string): string;
var
  sl: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // Prevent the stringlist from using spaces as delimiters too.
    sl.StrictDelimiter := True;

    // Set the comma separated text.
    sl.CommaText := Value;

    // Trim each item.
    for i := 0 to sl.Count -1 do
      sl[i] := Trim(sl[i]);

    // Concat back to comma separated string.
    Result := sl.CommaText;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Possibly the most useful component ever

Comment: Apart from it not being a component, I totally agree. TStringList saved my life many times.

Comment: @HughJones: Is not a component (don't derive from TComponent). But you're right: this thing is damn useful... ;-)

Comment: This is very inefficient, not to mention slow. There are faster solutions (see Arnaud's answer). There are more intuitive solutions, and possibly even more efficient (my answer).

Comment: This removes spaces from the start and end of the string as well. I don't think they're supposed to be removed, though, since they don't abut a delimiter.

Comment: @Rob - you are right on a strict interpretation of what the OP asked for, but the consensus is this is what he wanted ;P

Comment: @Rob, but that is exactly the desired output as stated in the question.

Comment: @Uwe, the question contradicts your statement two ways. First, it asks to remove spaces "*ONLY* if they appears before or after the comma char." Capitals and italics make that a pretty strong requirement. Second, Fabio's code removes only the spaces that are next to the delimiter.

Comment: You have a strange understanding of the word *consensus*, @Hugh. I see absolutely no discussion of whether this is what Fabio wanted until I brought it up, so I'm not sure how you could have thought there was consensus. Even if there was before, there isn't anymore.

Comment: @Rob, I'm referring to the "I would like the following output:" section. Perhaps he didn't grasp the correct description of what he really wants nor does his code do like that.

Comment: @Uwe, since the input doesn't have leading or trailing spaces, we cannot use the output as an example of what to do about leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: @Rob - you were quite right and the consensus may have been wrong.  Alternatively the poster may have been misleading but somehow we all missed it.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I cannot get your code to compile under v6 or v7.  Is the StrictDelimiter property only in later versions ?

Comment: Delphi 2006 and later will support this solution

Comment: @HughJones I thought it was introduced in Delphi 7, but it could be later too. I'm quite certain the property indeed doesn't exist in 6. But who is using those old versions anyway? ;)

Comment: @CosminPrund Slow is relative. Regular expressions are slow too and aren't that easier or more intuitive to use. Your solution is reasonably intuitive, but is really really really inefficient. Arnauds solution is very good, but not easy to write. I would myself write a similar solution, but only it speed was important. If it is for de-spacing small amounts of small strings, this is fast enough.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I am, unfortunately.

Comment: @GolezTrol: my office still uses v6.

Comment: StrictDelimiter property is pure evil, @Hugh Jones surround offending line with $IF RTLVersion >= 18.0 / $IFEND

Comment: @Hugh and Remy okay, some people are and I got some projects that also still use D7. Still, I don't think you can blame me if I use features that have been around for at least 5 years, unless a specific version is specified.

Comment: @user539484 Evil? Why? It's only evil that you need it. It should always be strict.

Comment: @Golez, my solution is not necessarily slower then yours! For the sample text provided, my solution does re-allocations of the string, while your solutions does a minimum of 7 reallocation. There's also the hidden cost of using `TStringList.CommaText`. If the text requires, on average, a number of deletion that's smaller then the number of delimited text sequences, my solution would be faster!

Comment: @Golez, about RegEx: They're not inherently slow. They're implemented using a very fast state machine. They appear slow because people some times use them for problems where they're not the optimal solution. This problem is a good example: Regex'es would be a poor choice for this problem, because they'd need to be applied  recursively.

Comment: @GolezTrol, exactly, it should not be lax by default. For such simple task you always have to add compile time conditional. This is evil.

Comment: @GolezTrol - No blame intended, but you might be interested to know that I have been working with D6/D7 for the last 3 contracts over a period of nearly six years.  I had a brief foray into d2006 a while back, but my experience is that hardly anyone is using versions later than d7.

Comment: @user539484 - problem is that the solution does not work properly without the StrictDelimiter because the stringlist will treat a ' ' as a delimiter.  I posted a D7 solution which is not quite as 'hard core' as some of the offerings here ~ comments appreciated.

Comment: @cosmin regex only bad solution when performance is critical. Otherwise it's easily the best solution. One simple line of code.

Answer (score 4):

A fast version could be:

```
function RemoveSpacesAroundDelimiter(const aString: string; aDelimiter: char = ','): string;
var S, D, D2: PChar;
begin
  SetLength(result,length(aString));
  if aString<>'' then
  begin
    S := pointer(aString);
    D := pointer(result);
    while S^<>#0 do
    begin
      if S^=' ' then
      begin
        D2 := D;
        repeat
          inc(S);
          D^ := ' ';
          inc(D);
        until S^<>' ';
        if S^=#0 then
          break;
        if S^=aDelimiter then
          D := D2; // trim spaces before comma
      end;
      D^ := S^;
      if (S[0]=aDelimiter) and (S[1]=' ') then
        repeat inc(S) until S^<>' ' else // trim spaces after comma
        inc(S);
      inc(D);
    end;
    SetLength(result,D-pointer(result));
  end;
end;
```

Some test code:

```
  assert(RemoveSpacesAroundDelimiter('one two,three')='one two,three');
  assert(RemoveSpacesAroundDelimiter('one two , three')='one two,three');
  assert(RemoveSpacesAroundDelimiter('one,two,three')='one,two,three');
  assert(RemoveSpacesAroundDelimiter('one   ,   two,  three')='one,two,three');
```

Comment: +1. I added a "fast" answer of my own, but deleted it because yours is faster.

Comment: Be careful. This code assumes the string doesn't contain any `#0` characters.

Comment: @RobKennedy A textual string is not meant to contain any #0 character, or it will break a lot of Windows API. Who will put a #0 in the middle of such an Unicode string?

Comment: @CosminPrund I liked your version. It is a clear sample of a state machine (my code hide this into code). So it did not sounds like a duplicate version to me.

Comment: If you want to differentiate between textual strings and other strings, that's fine. (The question didn't say.) I still think it's important to point out the assumption here with your answer, though, if not for Fabio's specific use, then for others who come here later with a similar task.

Answer (score 3):

Copy characters one-by-one into the destination buffer, but look for spaces and delimiters, and remember the last location you copied a non-space character into. If you see a space and the last non-space you copied was the delimiter, then skip the space. If it's a space and the last character you copied *wasn't* the delimiter, then copy it to the destination, but remember the last non-space you added. That way, if you see a delimiter later, you can go back and overwrite it.

```
function RemoveSpacesAroundDelimiter(const AString: string; ADelimiter: Char): string;
var
  c: Char;
  dest: Integer;
  LastNonSpace: Integer;
  HaveDelimiter: Boolean;
begin
  Assert(ADelimiter <> ' ');
  SetLength(Result, Length(AString));
  dest := 1;
  LastNonSpace := 0;
  HaveDelimiter := False;
  for c in AString do begin
    if (c = ' ') and HaveDelimiter then
      continue; // Skip this character

    if c = ADelimiter then begin
      dest := LastNonSpace + 1;
      HaveDelimiter := True;
    end else
      HaveDelimiter := False;
    Result[dest] := c;
    if c <> ' ' then
      LastNonSpace := dest;
    Inc(dest);
  end;
  SetLength(Result, dest - 1);
end;
```

Comment: Conceptually identical to Arnaud's solution. More readable because you don't use pointers, less efficient because Delphi inserts guard code every time you do `Result[dest] := c`

Comment: Upvoted this. If I wanted better performance than my stringlist solution, I would choose this one. It's great balance between performance and readability.

Comment: @GolezTrol that's a matter of taste. Personally to me oftern pointer to current char is easier to read and grasp than combination of string var + current index. That is just one variable less to keep in memory :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Delphi XE or above you can do this trivially in a single line of code, using a regular expression.

```
program regex;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  RegularExpressions;

const
  Input = 'This , is,       the Delphi  ,    World!';

begin
  Writeln(TRegEx.Replace(Input, ' *, *', ','));
  Readln;
end.
```

Naturally this is not the fastest running of the solutions on offer, but maybe that doesn't matter to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions. You want to find the delimiter preceded or followed by any number of spaces, and replace it all with a single copy of the delimiter.

```
function RemoveSpacesAroundDelimiter(const AString: string; const ADelimiter: string): string;
var
  re: TPerlRexEx;
begin
  re := TPerlRegEx.Create;
  try
    re.RegEx := '\s*' + TPerlRegEx.EscapeRegExChars(ADelimiter) + '\s*';
    re.Subject := AString;
    re.Replacement := TPerlRegEx.EscapeRegExChars(ADelimiter);
    re.ReplaceAll;
    Result := re.Subject;
  finally
    re.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Newer Delphi versions can use the built-in [RegularExpressionCore](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RegularExpressionsCore) unit. Older versions can use the equivalent [PerlRegEx unit from Jan Goyvaerts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html).

[Mick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12458/mick) previously posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066707/how-to-remove-space-around-a-character/8066864#8066864) demonstrating this, but he deleted it because he got the regular expression wrong (deleting *all* spaces instead of just the ones abutting the delimiter).

Comment: Rob, the unit you are supposed to interact with is called `RegularExpressions`. In turn it uses `RegularExpressionCore` as the engine. The high level unit allows very concise code as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler and easiest way is to use regular expressions. The last thing you would need is a huge complicated code block to solve such a simple  problem. Unfortunatly I don't have Delphi with me right now, I can't test this code, but if it's nothing exactly like this, it's very very close:

```
s := 'This , is,       the Delphi  ,    World!';
RegEx := TRegEx.Create('[ ]*,[ ]*');
CleanStr := RegEx.Replace(s, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this solution:

```
slValores.DelimitedText := StringReplace(sListSummary,' ','',[rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was worth adding because it will work with early versions of Delphi, which the stringlist solution (which I liked) does not.

It is alo reasonably quick, I believe, and fairly simple to read and understand.

```
function TForm1.UltraTrim(const InString : String; Delim : Char) : String;
var
  Buf : String;
  i : Integer;
  Token : String;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Trim(InString) <> '' then begin
    i := 1;
    Buf := StringReplace(InString, Delim, #0, [rfReplaceAll]) + #0;
    while i < Length(Buf) do begin
      Token := StrPas(@Buf[i]);
      i := i + Length(Token) + 1;
      Result := Result + Delim + Trim(Token);
    end;
    Result := Copy(Result,2,Length(Result));
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jedi Code Library, answer by @GolezTrol can be reformulated using one-liner.

```
function UltraTrim(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := JclStringList.Split(Value, ',').Trim.Join(',')
end;
```

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface
- http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:JclStringList

Answer (score 0):

with this function :

```
function MBTrim(iStr :string):string;
const CTc= 3{Conditions Count};
      CT :array[0..(CTc-1),0..1]of string= ( (' ,', ','), (', ', ','), ('  ', ' ') );
var   i  :Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to CTc-1 do while Pos(CT[i,0], iStr) > 0 do
    iStr:= StringReplace(iStr, CT[i,0], CT[i,1], [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  Result:= Trim(iStr);
end;
```

you can add other conditions simply.

for example i add `('  ', ' ')` to convert space between words like :

```
'This , is,       the       Delphi  ,    World!'
```

Answer (score -2):

Changed, one more time.

```
  while (pos(', ',s)>0) or (pos(' ,',s)>0) do   begin
    s := StringReplace(s, ', ', ',', [rfReplaceAll]);
    s := StringReplace(s, ' ,', ',', [rfReplaceAll]);   end;
```

OK for all the Delphi versions.

Comment: -1 No. That does remove all whitespaces and is identical to `Trim(s)`

Comment: But that would also remove the blank between "the" and "Delphi".

Comment: @Smasher, Trim(s) only removes whitespace at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: doesn't work if there are multiple spaces before or after the delimiter, see my original post for a revisited version.

Comment: @philnext: what about multiple whitespaces?

Comment: This code removes the wrong number of spaces *and* the wrong number of commas. It doesn't even work for the test case given in the question.

Comment: And it's *still* wrong. Once you fix the last typo, can you describe how it compares to the code suggested in the question?

Comment: @RobKennedy Why wrong ? My errors where fixed. No ? You're wright my first comment was not very constructive...I have add another one.

Comment: It fails for the following input: `hello ,world!`. (The loop body never executes.)